# Is there a COM interface for Edge Chromium similar to that provided by Internet Explorer?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Internet Explorer provides a COM interface that allows full control of an IE instance and navigating the DOM of a loaded web page.  Does Edge Chromium provide something similar?

I currently use PowerShell scripts to open IE, browse to a number of pages and navigate the DOM on each page to extract data from elements on each page, so wanted to do the same using Ede Chromium.

Comment: Have any searches for such a COM interface turned up any results?

Comment: If you think that using the Microsoft web driver can help to achieve the desired result then I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is "no, it doesn't".

Edge doesn't provide a COM interface for the same level as control as the Internet Explorer COM interface.

Selenium doesn't offer the same level of control as the IE COM interface and so isn't much use for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automate the Edge Chromium browser like you are automating the IE browser using PowerShell script.

To automate the Edge Chromium browser, I suggest trying to use the [Microsoft web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Selenium web driver supports many developing languages, you can choose the desired language.

Here are steps to automate the Edge Chromium browser using a web driver in C# language.

1. Download the correct [Microsoft WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) version for your build of Microsoft Edge.
2. Create a C# Console application in the Visual Studio.
3. Install the **Selenium.webDriver** and **Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools** packages via Nuget package manager.
4. Add the code below and modify the paths in the code.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.UseChromium = true;
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
           
            var driver = new Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools.EdgeDriver(@"--<Edge web driver path>--", options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("--<URL of the site>--");
}
```

Further, you can modify the code example as per your own requirements.

Comment: Is this I can do on a production machine? Selenium is a test driver...

Comment: Selenium doesn't offer the same level of control as the IE COM interface and so isn't much use for my use case, hence I haven't flagged this response as _the_ answer.